# Pass request result to view

Tags: electron

I'm new to Electron and I stuck with how to pass request result to view.

Here is the js file:

```
const request = require('request');

let serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

request.get({
    url: serverUrl + '/properties'
}, handleResponse);

var properties = {};

function handleResponse(error, response, body) {
    properties = JSON.parse(response.body);
    console.log(properties);
}
```

And here is the html part:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="title">General</div>
    <script>
        const { remote } = require('electron');
        console.log(properties);
        for (var i in remote.properties) {
            document.write('<p>' + remote.properties[i] + '</p>');
        }
    </script>
```

I know the request is async and that's why the `console.log(properties)` from the view print `{}`. So is there any way to send the request result to the view ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either dispatch the request from the renderer process and deal with the response in the callback that is executed after the data is received or make the request in the main process and then send a message to the renderer.

## Option 1: Request and handling within renderer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    const request = require('request')

    let serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api'

    request.get({
        url: serverUrl + '/properties'
    }, handleResponse)

    function handleResponse(error, response, body) {
        properties = JSON.parse(response.body)
        for (var i in properties) {
            document.write('<p>' + properties[i] + '</p>')
        }
    }

</script>
</html>
```

## Option 2: Request in main, send response to renderer

Main:

```
const request = require('request')
let serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api'

request.get({
    url: serverUrl + '/properties'
}, handleResponse)

function handleResponse(error, response, body) {
    properties = JSON.parse(response.body)
    mainWindow.webContents.send('my_message', properties)
}
```

Renderer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    require('electron').ipcRenderer.on('my_message', function(e, message) {
        console.log(message)
        for (var i in message) {
            document.write('<p>' + message[i] + '</p>');
        }
    });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Your answer is more complete

Answer (score 1):

I finally find a solution by encapsulate the request within a function with a callback as below:

```
function getProperties(callback) {
    request.get({
        url: serverUrl + '/properties'
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        callback(JSON.parse(response.body));
    });
}
```

Now from the view I just have to call the `getProperties`:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="title">General</div>
    <script>
        getProperties((properties) => {
            console.log(properties);
        });
    </script>
</div>
```